# Use only video stream for input files in ffmpeg concat demux

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm using ffmpeg concat demuxer to combine similar files: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

My input files have different lengths for video and audio streams. But are otherwise same in every regard, which is why I'm using concat demuxer.

This is resulting in the final output being un-seekable at certain timestamps.

Similar to this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/ffmpeg-concat-demuxer-corrupted-output-freezed-video-on-some-concatenated-parts

But in my case, I don't care much about the audio stream and would rather it be discarded, if that helps since then there won't be two streams of different duration - just a single video stream.

The documentation seems to imply this may be possible, that you can choose which stream to consider for input.

Is that possible? I.e. omit audio streams from the input files when concatenating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) or `-an` option.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -map 0:v -c copy output.mp4
```

Using these options will disable the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior which would otherwise automatically choose an audio stream.